# Twilio - Call and play mp3

Tags: twilio

Trying to test Twilio to migrate from Tropo, We alreaddy installed the libraries and tested sucessfully quickstart example https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/php.
But got stuck trying to do a call and play a mp3 file.

Having next PHP function:

```
public function call_twilioAction(){
        $account_sid = '******************************';
        $auth_token = '*****************************';
        $twilio_number = "NUMBER";

        // call  to my office
        $to_number = "NUMBER";

        $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
        $client->account->calls->create(  
            $to_number,
            $twilio_number,
            array(
                "url" => "https://arantec.smartyplanet.com/twilo/voice.xml"
        );
        return $this->render('::base.json.twig', array("data" => array()));
    }
```

And inside the voice.xml file:

```
<Response>
  <Play>https://arantec.smartyplanet.com/twilo/Smartyalert_es.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

As you can check, both files (xml, mp3) are accessible from internet, and are in the same called function host, where is the problem?

Still getting the error:

```
Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException:  (uncaught exception) at Twilio/Http/CurlClient.php line 41
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I assume all `NUMBER` values are just placeholders and you have valid phone numbers there?

Comment: Yes, phone numbers are there and work doing the quickstart example.

Comment: Seems silly but maybe Twilio really wants your XML responses to contain the XML preamble `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks @Cody Caughlan.

Comment: Code works in my localhost, not in the server. I guess is a Curl problem. I don't know if cause is using a twilio trial accout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So!! Finally I found out the problem in server side. As our server is ssl-secured we had to modify /Twilio/Http/CurlClient.php addind next line to access to a non ssl-secured server.

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Thanks everybody!

Comment: You shouldn't need to hack the `CurlClient.php` core. You can do this in your calling code when instantiating your Twilio REST Client. You first create your own CurlClient and pass in an array of those curl options to its initializer; then pass that pre-configured httpclient into the constructor of your rest client and you should be good to go. Unfortunately this comment doesnt allow an adequate code example.

Comment: Hi Cody! I tryed what you said:
        $options = array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);
        $curlClient = new CurlClient($options);
        $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token,null,$curlClient);
But not works. So I have to leave CurlClient.php hacked.